# Is it best practice to include an else: pass statement at the end of a Python if or if/elif statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

If I write:

```
if a == b:
    # do something
elif a == c:
    # do something else
```

and I just want to pass otherwise, is writing out the following required at the end?:

```
else:
    pass
```

It seems to run fine without the `else:` statement in the interpreter, is there a reason I'm not aware of that I should always include `else: pass` in these cases?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it isn't, the `else` suite is entirely optional.

From the [`if` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement):

> ```
> if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
> ```

```
             ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
             ["else" ":" suite]
```

where `(...)*` means *zero or more*, and `[...]` means *optional*. So a valid `if` compound statement has an `if` line and suite, 0 or more `elif` lines and corresponding suites, and at most one `else` line and suite, which is optional.

The Python compiler will ignore any `else: pass` block, there is really no point in including it:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('''\
... if True:
...     foo
... else:
...     pass
... ''', '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       13

  2           6 LOAD_NAME                1 (foo)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 13)

  4     >>   13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile('''\
... if True:
...     foo
... ''', '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       13

  2           6 LOAD_NAME                1 (foo)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 13)
        >>   13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

where the only difference is the line number attached to the `LOAD_CONST` bytecode because of the extra lines in the first source sample.

Stylistically, `else: pass` is just clutter, something to reduce readability.

Answer (score 3):

Don't ignore a 'better practice' even though there may be no 'best practice'.

An 'else:' clause certainly is not required, however... Logic and syntax rules aside, using an 'if-elif-elif-elif...else: pass' block provides the perfect opportunity for the author to document what conditions have NOT yet been met after possibly many if-elif checks. In the future should an unexpected 'corner case' raise its ugly head this bit of documentation may very well help to find the bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put `else` after an `if`, or an `elif` statement. The only place that you would need to use one is if you want to do something if the `if` statement was not true. For example:

```
if a == b:
    myString = "true"
else:
    myString = "false";
```