# Python count grouped items in a list

Tags: python-2.7

**Example of the problem.**

I have a list in which some elements contain bold tags which identify the groupings of the other elements. For example:

```
list_a = ['1','<b>a</b>','2','3','<b>bi</b>','<b>bii</b>','4', '<b>c</b>', '5']
```

I want to know how the non-bold strings are grouped together between the bold tags. My output will be:

```
grouped = [2,1,1]
```

**Edit: My actual code/problem is below.**

**My code.**

```
import scraperwiki
import urllib2
import re

# URL for scraping - Use sparingly.
url = 'http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/Lists/CMC%20%20PublicaesFicheiros/Attachments/89/Lista%20de%20Institui%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20Registadas%20(actualizado%2004.07.16).pdf'

# Open URL, read information.
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
xml=scraperwiki.pdftoxml(u.read()) # interpret as xml
u.close()

# Get text from xml.
text = re.findall(r'>(.*)</text>', xml)

# Remove empty strings and empty tags.  
text = [i.strip() for i in text if not len(i) == 1 if not i == '<b> </b>']

# Replace characters as needed.
text = [i.replace('&amp;','&') for i in text]

# Remove title and headers.
start = 0
for i in text:
    if '<b>' not in i: start += 1
    else: break

# This is the list.
text = text[start:]
```

**My current working solution.**

```
# Work out how the records are grouped together.
count = 0
grouped = []
for i in text:
    # If count is zero no grouping has yet been counted - nothing to count.
    if '<b>' in i and count != 0:
        # Append the number showing how many records are in the group.
        grouped.append(count)
        # Reset the counter before counting items in the next group.
        count = 0

    elif i.isnumeric():
        count += 1

    else: pass

# Append the count of the final grouping.
grouped.append(count)
```

Is there a better/more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `else: pass`? Just remove it.

Comment: (Link to [codereview.se] so you can repost it there.)

Comment: Isn't it best practice to include an else?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the indent.

Comment: I don't think it is, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865572/is-it-best-practice-to-include-an-else-pass-statement-at-the-end-of-a-python-if)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre SO gets weird. If you don't write code in the question it is closed because "have tried something before asking", if you write code it is closed because "off-topic, belongs to code review".

Comment: @Andrey: not true. I sometimes write some snippets of code on a non-code question, and I fix code when it's not working. Here it was working, and not very bad, so... It's only my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `itertools` here:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, groupby

list_a = ['1','<b>a</b>','2','3','<b>bi</b>','<b>bii</b>','4', '<b>c</b>', '5']
res = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(dropwhile(lambda L: '<b>' not in L, list_a), str.isnumeric) if k]
# [2, 1, 1]
```

Broken down to make it clearer what's happening:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, groupby

def count(iterable):
    # Ignore everything until the first `<b>`
    start_at = dropwhile(lambda L: '<b>' in L, iterable)
    # Groupby whether it's a numeric or not 
    grouped = groupby(start_at, str.isnumeric)
    # Loop over each key and group (key will be True for numeric values)
    for k, g in grouped:
        # The group will contain one or more numeric values
        if k:
            # yield the length of the group
            yield len(list(g))

res = list(count(list_a))
```

Comment: This code is barely readable, not sure if I would recommend it.

Comment: @Andrey I've broken it out to make it (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Comment: Is this a problem with not including parens for isnumeric?

Comment: @Astrophe nope - if you're getting that error - how does `i.isnumeric()` work  in your original code?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: @Astrophe you get the same error in your original code?

Comment: Yes. I have used isnumeric() in other places and it is not throwing an error.

Comment: I don't mean that to say I think it is a problem with the parentheses - I mean it is not an problem with unicode/ascii.

Comment: @JonClements isnumeric is method of unicode. This works in python3 where strings are unicode by default.

Comment: I am using python 2 but I have set the encoding to unicode on the first line with # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: @Astrophe oh - replace `str.isnumeric` with either `str.isdigit` or `unicode.isnumeric` then

Comment: unicode.isnumeric works. When I try this solution with my actual code (now added to the question) I get a list of 1s.

Comment: @Astrophe: The `# -- coding: utf-8 --` directive tells the Python interpreter that the text of the script itself is encoded with UTF-8. That influences how Python interprets literal strings in the script itself, but it has absolutely _no_ effect on how your script processes data.

Comment: What I really wanted to do was tell python 2 it would be dealing with non-ascii characters.

Comment: @Astrophe what with one thing and another - the original question was misleading - it looked like Python 3 as you didn't state the encoding... or have `u` prefixed strings, and ultimately your question is now about properly parsing XML/HTML which is a completely different question and problem entirely...

Comment: I was looking for a more pythonic way of solving the problem about grouping together the elements in a list.

Comment: @Astrophe does this answer not do that?

Comment: Your solution currently gives me a list of 1s. I think it may be close to an answer but it does not group together the items in my list.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import *

def iter_len(i):
    return sum(1 for _ in i)

print [
    iter_len(v)
    for k, v in groupby(text, key=lambda x: '<b>' in x)
    if not k
]
```

Comment: I am not getting the correct groupings with this code.

Comment: @Astrophe examples? for the sample you gave it gives me same output

Comment: I have added my code to the question. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Astrophe well not much you should test on isolated and reproducible test of data not a whole huge document

Comment: I was not sure about adding my code but at least it offers a useful example.