# Running this never ends -adding certain cell values together in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file and I want to add every three cells of a column together. I first have some checks and then I try to add them.  the piece of code that I have written never stops or ends. Any idea why?

this is a snapshot of the data: I try to add every three values for every column starting from Column G. dataframe's shape is (808597, 54).

[image]

```
for row in range (0,len(dataframe5.index)-2):

    if dataframe5.iloc[row, 5] == dataframe5.iloc[row+1, 5] and dataframe5.iloc[row, 5] == dataframe5.iloc[row+2, 5] and \
            dataframe5.iloc[row, 1] == dataframe5.iloc[row+1, 1] and dataframe5.iloc[row, 1] == dataframe5.iloc[row+2, 1]:

        for i in range(6, len(dataframe5.columns)):
             dataframe5.iloc[row, i]= dataframe5.iloc[row, i]+ dataframe5.iloc[row+1, i] + dataframe5.iloc[row+2, i]
```

Comment: Please explain the context, what you're trying to do and provide example input data and the matching expected output

Comment: Try to print length of dataframes in the loop.

Comment: (808597, 54)
this is the shape

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to some possible reasons. For instance, in certain situations, the size of your DataFrame with the way your loops are coded can cause some processes to take very long.

You may want to test the code on a small subset of the data, such as 20 rows. Then, add `print` statements to print a message after each `if` and `for` block (e.g. "Check 1", "Check 2") to first check if the `if` and `for` conditions are being met for this small subset of the data.

For the full dataset, you may also try adding an `else` statement such as:

```
else:
    pass
```

There might be some rows causing your `if` condition to be perpetually met that you don't know about. Generally, such code has to be coded carefully to catch all possible cases (for which the remainder not covered by `if` will be covered by `else`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865572/is-it-best-practice-to-include-an-else-pass-statement-at-the-end-of-a-python-if/55856448#55856448) for a little more explanation.